# Error("NotYetImplemented") SSR Angular 8 serve error

Tags: angular, angular8, server-side-rendering

When I run this command "npm run build:ssr && npm run serve:ssr" i get error like this

/Users/apple/Documents/honadon/temporaryquickapp/Honadon-master/Source/XonadonUz/ClientApp/dist/server.js:96153
  throw new Error("NotYetImplemented");
  ^

Error: NotYetImplemented
    at HTMLCanvasElement.exports.nyi (/Users/apple/Documents/honadon/temporaryquickapp/Honadon-master/Source/XonadonUz/ClientApp/dist/server.js:96153:9)
    at Object. (/Users/apple/Documents/honadon/temporaryquickapp/Honadon-master/Source/XonadonUz/ClientApp/dist/server.js:300784:48)
    at **webpack_require** (/Users/apple/Documents/honadon/temporaryquickapp/Honadon-master/Source/XonadonUz/ClientApp/dist/server.js:20:30)
    at Object.hasImageData (/Users/apple/Documents/honadon/temporaryquickapp/Honadon-master/Source/XonadonUz/ClientApp/dist/server.js:300497:20)
    at **webpack_require** (/Users/apple/Documents/honadon/temporaryquickapp/Honadon-master/Source/XonadonUz/ClientApp/dist/server.js:20:30)
    at Object. (/Users/apple/Documents/honadon/temporaryquickapp/Honadon-master/Source/XonadonUz/ClientApp/dist/server.js:300488:17)
    at **webpack_require** (/Users/apple/Documents/honadon/temporaryquickapp/Honadon-master/Source/XonadonUz/ClientApp/dist/server.js:20:30)
    at Module. (/Users/apple/Documents/honadon/temporaryquickapp/Honadon-master/Source/XonadonUz/ClientApp/dist/server.js:299934:78)
    at **webpack_require** (/Users/apple/Documents/honadon/temporaryquickapp/Honadon-master/Source/XonadonUz/ClientApp/dist/server.js:20:30)
    at Module. (/Users/apple/Documents/honadon/temporaryquickapp/Honadon-master/Source/XonadonUz/ClientApp/dist/server.js:293211:76)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

I tried to use canvas only in browser like this

```
constructor( @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object) {
    this.isBrowser = isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId);
  }
```

[image]